# redirect is not working in both php & javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I had write some script, i tried Header & window.location both for redirection, but in this page redirect is not working...in other pages javascript window.location is working perfectly...

```
$insertquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(UserName, Password, FirstName, LastName, Address, ContactNo, Url, Birthdate, Gender, profImage,curcity, age, married_status, college_name, batch, qualification, specilization, public_message)VALUES('$login','$password','$fname','$lname','$address','$cnumber','$email','$bday','$gender','$propic','$address','$age','$married_status','$coll','$batch','$qua','$specilization','$public_message')") or die(mysql_error());

 /*$page = "signup-success.php";                          
echo '<script>window.location = "'.$page.'";</script>';                                  
echo "login success";*/    

if($insertquery){
  $from = "admin@doctorskynet.com    "; // sender
  $subject = "Thank You For Registering Doctorskynet.com";
  $message = "Welcome to Doctorskynet.com"."<br/>";
  $message .= "Username:".$login."<br/>";
  $message .= "Password:".$password."<br/>";    
  $message = "Please click below link to activate your account<br/>";            

  // send mail
  //$mail = mail($email,$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
  session_start();

  //Create query
  $qry="SELECT * FROM members WHERE UserName='clean($login)' AND Password='$password'";
  $result=mysql_query($qry);

  //Check whether the query was successful or not
  if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      //Login Successful
      session_regenerate_id();
      $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
      $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['member_id'];
      $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['FirstName'];
      $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $member['FirstName'].'-'.$member['LastName'];
      $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['profImage'];

      $online = 1;                          
      //Update query      
      mysql_query("UPDATE members SET online = $online WHERE member_id='".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] ."'");

      session_write_close();
      $page = "Home.php";                          
      echo '<script>window.location = "'.$page.'";</script>';  

      /*header("location: Home.php");
      exit();*/
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting some test strings instead of the redirects then viewing the source to see if they show up? Have you inspected the request for errors with a browser inspector?

Answer (score 1):

When using `header()` you're supposed to specify a full URL and I think `Location` needs a capital L:

```
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/Home.php");
exit;
```

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by "not working". What is happening? What are you expecting to happen? Are all your queries executing successfully?

Comment: means its not redirecting to Home.php page. 

my insert query is working, that user is creating correctlly...i tried javascript rediect also, using that also page is not redircting. this is happening only in this page. i used header in other page also, that pages are working fine

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is will help for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

window.location.replace("siteurl");

The above code will tell the script type to browser .I think you are missing the script type.

Comment: i tried this one also but still its not working.i dont no y its not working